# Creat a layout contain 6 square child layout?

Tags: android, layout

I want to create a layout and it contain `6 square child layout`.

Will it be a right approach to create **a square layout and set it to 6 child layout**?

Comment: You probably can get a GridView to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

use [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) if you don't want to use adapter for filling that, but you cat also review [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) abilities for your own